# Translate "Sorry, no quotes are available for this order at this time"

Tags: localisation, translate, inline-translations

Since we use table rates and require a city/state/zip, a customer will always see "Sorry, no quotes are available for this order at this time" before choosing their shipping criteria.  We want to edit or remove this text.

Adding translate in i18n for this statement, unlike the rest of the cart, doesn't work.

Any suggestion on where to remove or change this text?  CSS to blank it out or remove it?

Comment: Where you added file and whats file name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer.  Currently Magento 2.4 doesn't overwrite the js-translation.json file when adding new translations, so you'll have to update the file yourself to add or remove knockout.js text.

Go to your `pub/static/frontend/theme/theme_style/en_US/` to edit the j`s-translation.json` file.

A bug has been filed on github when this appeared on 2.3 and is still open.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to come from : `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/cart/shipping-rates.html`

The translation should work.

If you want to remove it then just extend the template and remove that part.

```
<!-- ko text: $t('Sorry, no quotes are available for this order at this time')--><!-- /ko -->
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it may be error of shipping method, select all countries and  select default shipping charges flat rate and than flush cache and check again